# Finding the order of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $x\in\mathbb{Z}/42$, and suppose that x has order $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$. Without listing all of the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}42$, determine all of the possible values that $n$ could be.

I'm having a hard time understanding the concept of the order of a group and don't know where to begin.

Comment: lagrange theorem?

Comment: $x$ is an element. We are talking about the order of an element. (Although if you incorporate Lagrange's, which is recommended, then you are using the order of the group.)

Comment: Would the possible values for n be 1, 4, and 5?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik how would I apply the Lagrange Theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Thanking Lagrange theorem we see that :

order of subgroup generated by $x$ should divide order of $\mathbb{Z}_{42}$..

please see that "order of an element is same as order of subgroup generated by that element"...

order of $\mathbb{Z}_{42}$ is $42$ So, divisors of $42$ are ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

So, order of group generated by $x$ should be ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

So, possible orders of $x$ should be ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

Comment: So it would be 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42?

Comment: Yes... that is it!

Answer (score 0):

The order of $x$ is the least $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $nx=0$. (*)

Write $x\in\mathbb{Z}/42$ as $x=y+42\mathbb{Z}$ with $y\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Now, $nx=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/42$ iff $ny$ is a multiple of $42$. This means that $ny=lcm(y,42)$. Now use that $lcm(y,42)gcd(y,42)=42y$ to conclude a restriction on $n$.

(*) We write this additively because it's the natural thing to do for $\mathbb{Z}/42$ and also because $\mathbb{Z}/42$ does have a separate but natural notion of multiplication, under which it is not a group.